# Oracle package for adding 2 numbers

Tags: oracle, package

I am learning oracle packages. I have created a package in that I created a procedure to add two numbers. Below is my syntax.

```
CREATE PACKAGE ADD2Numbers AS
    PROCEDURE ADD1(A IN NUMBER ,B IN number ,C OUT Number );
END ADD2Numbers;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY  ADD2Numbers AS 
    PROCEDURE ADD1(A IN NUMBER ,B IN number ,C OUT Number ) IS 
    BEGIN
       C:=A + B;
    END ADD1;
END ADD2Numbers;
```

I am calling this procedure as below.

```
 Declare C Number; call ADD2Numbers.ADD1(1,2); Print :c;
```

But I get the below error.

> call ADD2Numbers.ADD1(1,2)
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD1'
>   06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that in reality, you wouldn't use a procedure with an `out` parameter for this sort of thing.  You'd use a function that returns a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE
C Number;

BEGIN
 ADD2Numbers.ADD1(1,2,C);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C);
END;
```

To view dbms output in SQL Developer:

1.Click View-> Dbms Output

2.Click on the green colored "+" icon on and dbms output window that opened by step 1 above.

3.Add the connection you are using

4.Run the above anonymous block again

Comment: Thanks . I am getting PL/SQL procedure successfully completed as a result. Should show the result. Any issue with my procedure

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a variable `c` but not passed it as a parameter to the procedure.  The number of parameters passed to a procedure must match its signature.

So the solution is quite simple (this is using SQL*Plus syntax):

```
define C Number; 
call ADD2Numbers.ADD1(1,2, :C);  
print  c;
```

---

As @JustinCave says, the normal way of implementing this sort of functionality is with a stored function.

```
CREATE PACKAGE ADD2Numbers AS
    FUNCTION ADD1(A IN NUMBER ,B IN number) return number;
END ADD2Numbers;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY  ADD2Numbers AS 
    FUNCTION ADD1(A IN NUMBER ,B IN number) return number IS 
       c number;
    BEGIN
       C:=A + B;
       return c;
    END ADD1;
END ADD2Numbers;
```

You could call it like this ...

```
select ADD2Numbers.ADD1(1,2) from dual;
```

... use it in PL/SQL like this ...

```
declare 
  x number;
begin
  x := ADD2Numbers.ADD1(1,2);
  dbms_output.put_line('x=' || to_char(x));
end;
```

Remember to enable SERVEROUTPUT when using DBMS_OUTPUT calls (most IDEs will do this be default).  [Find out more](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/serveroutput.html).

Comment: Thanks . value of C is not showing. Any issue with my procedure.?

Comment: It should work.  most likely it's a problem with how you call your program.